# How to save array data in UITableViewCell in Swift3

Tags: ios, arrays, tableview, swift3

I want a cell in `UITableView` to have an array of `String`. In order to do this, I set three variables of Type array called `myArray`, `passedArrayData` and,`twodArray` in my `SecondTableVewController` file. The passedArrayData is for cells to be displayed. They have array of `string`. And in my `firstTableViewController`, I have created;

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let viewcontroller = SecondViewController()
    let getData = UserDefaults.standard.array(key: "twoDarray") as! [[String]]
    viewcontroller.myArray = getData[indexPath.row]
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewcontroller, animated: true)
}

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = title[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: familyFont, size: 19)
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 19)

    return cell
}
```

Here is **SecondViewController** code;

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = _titile
    data()

    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

}

  func data(){
    if let items = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "twodArray") as? [[String]] {
        for item in 0...items.count {
            index = item
            let string = items[index]
            passedArrayData = string
            twodArray.append(passedArrayData)
        }
    }
}

 func setTitleName(){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: ".....", message: "...", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let save = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: {
        (UIAlertAction) -> Void in

        let textInput = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField

        self.myArray.append(textInput.text!)
        self.twodArray.append(self.myArray)

        let saveData = UserDefaults.standard
        saveData.set(self.twodArray, forKey: "twodArray")
        saveData.synchronize()

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            () -> Void in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })

    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: {
        (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in

        textField.placeholder = "...."
    })

    alert.addAction(save)
    alert.addAction(cancel)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

cell.textLabel?.text = myArray[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: familyFont, size: 19)
cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 19)

return cell
```

}

I have no idea how to let each selected cell to store an array of `String`. For example, when you click on a cell and goes to the `SecondTableViewController` where you can store text by `UITextField`, and let's say you make five cells by entering String five times in `UITextField`. And when you go back to `FirtsTableView` controller and you click on a different cell, which has nothing until some text is stored.

What I want to accomplish is;

1. Save data correctly with `Userefault`for my code.
2. let each cell to have an array of string that is displayed on the secondTableViewController

There are many errors that I can't fix. If you know what I mean and want to achieve, it is very helpful to make code that works for this.

Your help is so huge to me. 
Thanks